# Computer freezes randomly after changing GPU

Tags: memory, graphics-card, motherboard, freeze, gpu

Last month I bought a brand new MSI GTX 1050 2GB. Installation went fine, but after testing it a little bit I noticed my monitor kept going black every now and then. Also, my PC would randomly completely freeze every now and then. For example, I could just be scrolling down on Facebook and then everything would go unresponsive (PC, keyboard [including NumLk, CapsLk and ScrLk lights] and mouse), forcing me to do a hard reset. To solve the first problem I decided to buy a new HDMI monitor (since my last screen was using VGA with a DVI adapter). For the second problem I DDU'd the older drivers, cleaned up my system and did a fresh install.

For a while, that was kinda it. The monitor would still go to black every now and then which I thought it was because of the HDMI cable I'm using (I just found it lying around, it's quite long and has no filters I think). But some days ago, the freezing problem came back again. Since then, the black screens have become more frequent and it kinda left me thinking all the problems are related and the first problem is not (just) because of the HDMI cable.

I don't think formatting will help since Windows isn't throwing any errors. Plus, when the black screen happens I can keep doing stuff, except that I can't see what I'm doing. Also, the PC has never blue-screened, it just freezes completely.

**Observations:**

- This PC build is from 2011-2012.
- Changes I've done to this build: Changed the CPU a couple of years ago, added an SSD a couple of months ago and finally, added this GPU on December.
- IMPORTANT: This GPU doesn't have a power connector. It takes power directly from my 2011-2012 motherboard.
- I haven't OC'd this GPU.
- My motherboard, RAM, HDD and PSU are from the original 2011-2012 build.
- Windows isn't reporting any problems in the Event Viewer.
- Windows Memory Diagnostic and System File Checker come out clean.
- [MemTest86 shows no errors at all (left it running for 18 hours).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUvSw.jpg)
- [Ran FurMark with extreme burn for 10 minutes without problems.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X95qK.jpg)
- [For reference, I recorded this video when the black screen was happening in my old monitor.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yDqIVo0kKec) The black screen problem with my current monitor is basically the same, minus the "new device found" sound.
- So far, the freezes have ONLY happened while doing non-intensive GPU operations (browsing Facebook, watching a YouTube video, looking for a program in my desktop). It has never happened while I'm gaming (and I play GPU intensive games).
- I usually have 20-30 Chrome tabs opened at the same time but suspended thanks to TheGreatSuspender. I've been doing this for many years now, so I doubt that's part of the problem.

**My specs:**

- Motherboard: Gigabyte GA-870A-USB3 v3
- CPU: HexaCore AMD FX-6300, 3826 MHz (19 x 201)
- RAM: x2 Kingston 99U5471-012.A00LF   4 GB DDR3-1333 DDR3 SDRAM
- SSD: KINGSTON SUV400S37240G (223 GB)
- HDD: SEAGATE ST2000DL003-9VT166
- GPU: MSI GeForce GTX 1050  (2 GT OC)
- PSU: Cooler Master GX 550W 80 PLUS

**Edits:**

1. I struggled a bit to insert the GPU because it has these 2 metal prongs that I had to insert into some tiny holes near the back panel of my case. I could finally insert it after moving it around a bit. But if I remember correctly (I'm at my job right now) there was no way to even wiggle it afterwards, and I even thought it was gonna be really hard to remove it later.
2. Two weeks after reinserting the GPU it happened again. [This time I recorded it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2e5pCc95Xkk). As you can see in the video, EVERYTHING is completely frozen. Also, the last thing I was doing was watching YouTube, nothing GPU intensive, not even in the background.
3. Also, there's something weird I noticed while reinserting the GPU. [I don't know if you can see it in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbHK4.jpg) but it looks like the GPU is leaving a gap in the socket on the right side. I don't know if this is normal but I cannot move it after it's inserted.
4. The blinking problem from my monitor is back. It also happens randomly and it looks like my monitor turns off for a couple of seconds and then turns back on. Also, the main freezing problem FINALLY happened while playing. As a side note, some weird artifacts and effects have started appearing while playing Overwatch (only game I currently play).

   - When I respawn, it looks like the model's hand clips to the infinity for a couple of seconds.
   - There are some weird black spots appearing randomly on some maps.
   - The game suddenly starts dropping frames (confirmed it's not network lag).

Comment: Have you tried to reinsert the GPU into the board? This looks like some electric problem (bad contact). Reinsert and doublecheck, that it holds firmly in the PCI-E slot may solve your problem.

Comment: Check out my first edit. I'll check the contact later tonight.

Comment: up to date bios ? tried older nvidia drivers ? what version of windows are you using ?

Comment: Yes, the bios is up to date. I don't think nvidia drivers are the problem because here, because no errors are being logged (neither in Event Viewer or nvidia logs). I'm currently using Windows 10 Creators Update.

Comment: Also, I reinstalled the GPU and so far, the problem has gone but I don't believe that it's solved since same thing happened after I used DDU. I'm gonna be testing for a couple more days and report back. Still open for more suggestions.

Comment: After 2 weeks, the problem happened again. Please my edits number 2 and 3 for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last month I bought a new PSU (EVGA SuperNOVA 650 G3, 80 Plus Gold 650W), and after much testing I can finally say the problem is solved. Seems like a faulty PSU can cause the system to freeze too. Also, considering the PSU was pretty old (as stated in the first post) I guess it was time to change it.

Thanks to all the people who tried to help, hope this is helpful for anyone else with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am agreeing with Jaroslav Kucera, what you've got is a faulty electric contact, almost surely in the connector. Some random vibrations after some time will throw it off; re-seating the board might fix it for some time, or even forever if you manage to get it exactly right.

What it looks like is, your case wasn't exactly designed for that board - it's out of tolerance by perhaps one or two millimeters or less. As a result, the board does not insert snugly and neatly, but needs to be forced out of true. In this kind of scenarios, you might experience freezes when the PC is warm, or when it's cold (if the thermal expansion is enough to trigger the effect), or when a heavy lorry passes by and makes the floor vibrate.

For a permanent solution, I'd look at where the board is forcing its way: there's somewhere a contrast between the GPU board and the PC assembly - for example in the slot insets at the back. Those you can perhaps file slightly to make a bit larger, and so seat better (only, be sure to catch all the metallic powder, which should never be allowed to float near the mainboard circuits). If the case allows it, you can loosen the back assembly so that it wiggles a bit, seat the GPU card, and re-tighten the back assembly.

**UPDATE**:
*"It looks like the GPU is leaving a gap in the socket"*

Yes, it looks like that. Assuming the board is not warped, and the connector is not warped either, this means that when the board is seated, the fit is not perfect - the board gets "pushed" laterally, and this affects the connector. It is an ideal scenario for a faulty, intermittent electrical contact.

Trying to "counter-warp" the connector might damage the connector and the motherboard. I can only repeat that there must be some point where the board is forced (either because the board is too long or the matched part of the case is too narrow); that's where you need to intervene.

<sup>I had a very similar problem with a Realtek network card years ago (when inserted with the motherboard and all outside of the case, everything would work; once inside, it would not even boot. *But* if I kept the card pushed downwards with a finger, *then* it would work). I ended up warping the case flange that was giving me troubles with a pair of pliers. Just a half millimeter perhaps, but it was enough (*then* the case would not close as easily as before, and I had to give the side panel a bit of encouragement too).</sup>

Comment: In the last 6 years I've had this case and motherboard I haven't got any trouble at all. I already tried reinserting the GPU two weeks ago, but the problem happened again today. Maybe it's not the board but the GPU that's not fitting properly. Please, check my second and third edits, ESPECIALLY my third edit.

Comment: In response to your update: That actually makes a lot of sense, since the card is taking power directly from the mobo!
The most notable difference between my old card and this new one is that this last one has 2 metal prongs that MUST be inserted into some tiny holes near the back of the case. That's why I can't move it freely, contrary to my old card.
Also, before I try going caveman with the pliers I'm gonna take my PC to where I bought my card since the warranty covers my entire PC. It's gonna take a few more days (no more than a week), but I'll report back as soon as I get an answer.

Comment: I had assumed that the warranty had expired, but if not, that is surely the best option!

Comment: Sorry for taking so long, many things happened. So far, I still don't know the cause of the problem. I took my full tower to the store, they checked it, told me it's in a really good state, checked the GPU, temps, etc., called an nVidia partner... and they told me they have NO CLUE what is going on. But they agree it MAY be because the motherboard is failing (for some reason). I sent the GPU to the official tech support so they can do all the corresponding tests, so it's another week to get some results. I couldn't send it earlier, but the problem got worse (check 4th edit) so I got no choice.

Comment: About the gap in the socket, they all told me there's no problem about it as long as the GPU is making contact with the motherboard. We even live tested it by moving the card around while playing some games or watching videos. Nothing happened. If nothing comes out from the official tech support report I think I'll just buy a new motherboard.